# Issue with ruby ActiveRecord gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using rails 4.2.4 version.
I have a database table 'upload' which has 10000 entries.

```
file_name | file_path | parent_directory | created_at
```

I have a model, Upload with following function:

```
select(:parent_directory).distinct
```

This should provide me a list of distinct parent directories present in the table.

When I do `select(:parent_directory).distinct.size`,
it executes `select distinct id from upload;`
and gives me all 10000 entries, which is wrong.

But when I do `select(:parent_directory).distinct.count`,
it executes `select distinct parent_directory from upload;`
and gives me 3000 entries, which is correct.

Is this some kind of issue with ActiveRecord gem or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue regarding this in the rails repo https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16182.

The problem is with size which is trying to make intelligent choices for you. If you use `length` instead of `size` you will have the expected result.